# InstallShield) Triggering Maintenance Mode when the remove button is clicked in Control Panel - Add or Remove Program

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I have a Basic MSI Project made with InstallShield 2019.

When the user presses the delete button on the *Add or Remove Programs* in the *Control Panel* after installing the program, 
I want to bring up the maintenance mode to the user (where the user can select a process with a [Modify, Repair, Remove button]), not just delete it.

Maintenance mode is shown as expected when I run *setup.exe* directly.

Is there any option for this in installshield 2019?

Comment: Thank you @Chris for editing my clumsy sentences.

Comment: No problem - I hope you don’t mind, and I hope I haven’t changed the meaning :)